# How to store more than 100 records using cosmos batch from azure cosmos db using query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I tried to create more than 100 documents in a batch and received a 400 (Bad Request) result from the server with the error Batch request has more operations than what is supported.

Creating 100 documents works fine. Clearly, there is a limit of 100 operations per batch.There's no documentation I could find anywhere the solution.

I can not store them in different batches because even if one doc fail to store I want others also to rollback. Any somebody please guide me how to achieve this using cosmos db?

Comment: *There's no documentation I could find anywhere the solution.* -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits states that the Maximum number of operations in a transactional batch is 100.

Comment: @PeterBons I saw this . Is there any other way to be able to store >100 records with in single transaction ? We opt for CosmosBatch bcz in case of any failure rollback was handled gracefully.

Comment: Sorry, not that I know.

Answer (score 1):

Transactional Batch has two upper-limits, size-wise (aside from the restriction that a batch must be within the same partition of the same collection):

- 100 items
- 2MB payload

Going beyond 100 items (or 2MB) will require you to iterate through multiple batches, checkpointing with each successfully-written batch. How you accomplish this is really up to you, as there is no mechanism built-in.

The limitations on batch item count and size are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/transactional-batch?tabs=dotnet#limitations).